JavaScript Chunk uploading file make browser lag
I'm trying to upload a file by chunking it and sending it to the server and in this code I just chunking and not doing with the chunks yet so the main problem is if the file is 2GB when I'm chunking it if the chunkCount be 1000 or more I'm ddos my server by multiple requests (is this right?) and if the chunkCount will be under 100 my client has so much lag
Why I don't upload file normally and do this chunk job ?
you can pause the uploading and if the uploading of a chunk field cause a connection issue you can retry from the field chunk


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Video Thumbnail Generator</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.12.10/dist/full.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="loading loading-spinner loading-lg"></span>
    <h1>File Chunk Processor</h1>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" />

    <button id="processButton" onclick="DoChunk()">Process File</button>

    <script>
      function DoChunk() {
        
        let chunkCount = 1700;
        let chunkIndex = 0;
        processNextChunk(chunkIndex, chunkCount);
      }

      function processNextChunk(chunkIndex, chunkCount) {
        if (chunkIndex < chunkCount) {
          processFileChunk('fileInput', chunkIndex, chunkCount, function () {
            setTimeout(() => {
              processNextChunk(chunkIndex + 1, chunkCount);
            }, 100); // Adjust the delay as needed
          });
        }
      }

      function processFileChunk(elementId, chunkIndex, chunkCount, callback) {
        // Get the file input element
        const inputElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

        // Check if the input element and file are available
        if (!inputElement || !inputElement.files || !inputElement.files[0]) {
          console.error('No file selected or element not found');
          return;
        }

        // Get the selected file
        const file = inputElement.files[0];

        // Calculate the size of each chunk
        const chunkSize = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkCount);
        const start = chunkIndex * chunkSize;
        const end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, file.size);

        // Create a Blob for the specific chunk
        const chunk = file.slice(start, end);

        // Create a FileReader to read the chunk
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (event) {
          // Get the chunk content as a Base64 string
          const base64String = event.target.result.split(',')[1]; // Remove data URL part

          // Output or process the chunk as needed
          console.log(`Chunk ${chunkIndex + 1} of ${chunkCount}:`);
          console.log(base64String);

          if (callback) {
            callback();
          }
        };

        reader.onerror = function (error) {
          console.error('Error reading file chunk:', error);
          if (callback) {
            callback();
          }
        };

        // Read the chunk as a Data URL (Base64 string)
        reader.readAsDataURL(chunk);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



and this is my API code which is asp.net and this get chunks as sting and inside string is long chunked base64
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadChunkAsync([FromBody] FileChunkRequest request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var requestToken = _jwtTokenRepository.GetJwtToken();
        var loggedInUser = _jwtTokenRepository.ExtractUserDataFromToken(requestToken);

        var blobTableClient = _blobClientFactory.BlobTableClient(TableName.StashChunkDetail);

        var stashChunkDetail = blobTableClient
            .Query<StashChunkDetail>(x => x.RowKey == request.UploadToken && x.UserId == loggedInUser.id)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (stashChunkDetail != null)
        {
            var currentChunkSize = request.Data.SizeMB();
            var isSizeOutOfDeal = stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedSizeMb + currentChunkSize >
                                  stashChunkDetail.FileSizeMb;
            var containerName = Enum.Parse<ContainerName>(stashChunkDetail.PartitionKey);

            if (isSizeOutOfDeal)
            {
                //delete table 
                // ReSharper disable once MethodSupportsCancellation
                await blobTableClient.DeleteEntityAsync(stashChunkDetail.PartitionKey, stashChunkDetail.RowKey);

                //delete commit data form blob storage
                await _fileUploadService.DeleteObjectAsync(containerName, stashChunkDetail.RowKey);

                return BadRequest(
                    $"the size of chunks is more than {stashChunkDetail.FileSizeMb} MB please request new upload token");
            }

            var isLast = (request.Data.SizeMB() + stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedSizeMb) >=
                         stashChunkDetail.FileSizeMb;

            int totalUploadedChunks = stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedChunks;
            int currentChunk;

            if (totalUploadedChunks == 0)
            {
                currentChunk = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                currentChunk = totalUploadedChunks + 1;
            }


            var fileChunkDto = new FileChunkDto()
            {
                FileFormat = stashChunkDetail.FileFormat,
                ContainerName = containerName,
                FileName = stashChunkDetail.RowKey,
                Data = request.Data,
                AccessTier = stashChunkDetail.AccessTier,
                CurrentChunk = currentChunk,
                TotalUploadedChunks = stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedChunks
            };

            await _fileUploadService.UploadChunkAsync(fileChunkDto, cancellationToken);


            stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedChunks += 1;
            stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedSizeMb += request.Data.SizeMB();

            // ReSharper disable once MethodSupportsCancellation
            await blobTableClient.UpdateEntityAsync(stashChunkDetail, ETag.All);

            var responseChunkProgress = new ChunkUploadResponse()
            {
                TotalUploadedChunks = stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedChunks,
                TotalUploadedSizeMB = stashChunkDetail.TotalUploadedSizeMb
            };

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, responseChunkProgress);
        }

        return BadRequest("Please Request New Upload Token");
    }


The code that you show us does not make any requests to a server. So we cannot judge whether a server might be overwhelmed by too many requests. Which requests to you intend to make?

To avoid overwhelming your server, you can wait for each request to finish before you process the next chunk of the file. The following snippet illustrates this (by posting every chunk to https://httpbin.org):


function upload(file, offset) {
  if (offset < file.size) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async function(event) {
      console.log(
        (
          await (
            await fetch("https://httpbin.org/anything", {
              method: "POST",
              body: reader.result
            })
          ).json()
        ).data
      );
      upload(file, offset + 128);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(offset, offset + 128));
  }
}
<input id="file" type="file" />
<button onclick="upload(file.files[0], 0)">Upload</button>




the server is asp.net api is getting the bas64 chunks as string and stash them into azure blob storage then i finalize the file by requesting to an other api , i added some api code

The pattern in my answer can also be applied for requests made to your ASP.net server.

should i change the api to stream type or this js code work without any api change because i sow the client is sending data:application/octet-stream witch my api only get a single sting base64 per request

You can use reader.readAsDataURL instead of reader.readAsArrayBuffer if your server prefers base64. My answer just gave an example.
